# SWIFT TableView error

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, text-files

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    let firstTable = [String]()
    let secondTable = [String]()

    var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Chapters", ofType: "txt")
    var data = String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
    var content = (data)
    var line: [String] = content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

**Error:**

> 'MasterViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'path'

The next Question for @dip >> why does the table print an initial empty string? text is printed in the second cell instead of starting at 0

```
var path: String?
var data: String?
var TableView1 = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("textFile", ofType: "txt")
    self.data = String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
    if var content = (data){
        //var line: [String] = content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        var chp: [String] = content.componentsSeparatedByString("#")

        TableView1 += chp
    }...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For computed Properties, you have to access via setter method, 
for example make optional global var like

```
var path:String?
```

and then lets say set value from **inside viewDidload** like

```
self.path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Chapters", ofType: "txt")
```

your error will go away! Hope it will help you!

Comment: lets say I'm using it in a tableview. will this allow me to call upon a line of text from the text file?

Comment: the answer i have provided is for 'MasterViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'path' error,
i guess it should work in context of your original question !

Comment: it did thanks for that. 
but now It prints the text in the second cell and not the first. any idea why?

Comment: it seems your are tracking line with \n escape sequence, conceptually it should work, please share your code so that it would be easy to comment ! and don't forgot to accept the answer if it helped you :D

Answer (score 1):

Following change may also work;

```
private class var path:String {
    get {
        return NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Chapters", ofType: "txt")!
    }
}

var data = String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong way to initialise your `data` instance. Instead of that do it in your class method suppose you can do it in `viewDidLoad` method like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Chapters", ofType: "txt")
    var data = String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
    var content = (data)
    var line: [String] = content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
}
```